# What's a good melee strategy for Teleglitch?

Tags: teleglitch

Melee weapons seem pretty strong against basic zombies (?) in teleglitch, I feel like I could save a lot more of my ammo for the bigger monsters if I could kill smaller things more consistently with whatever melee weapon I'm holding.

Problem is, I have difficulty getting consistent hits with the thing. The hitbox seems weighted towards one side of the avatar and that makes it a bit difficult to use.

Any tips that will help me score more hits and rely more on my melee for basic combat?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the side where the knife renders toward enemy and constantly backpedal. That is the basics of my knife strategy.

Edit: at an angle toward enemy rather.

After having done some more melee to try out what works best I found that for me it works better if I time my stabs rather than spamming the attack button. Takes more practice but it seems more consistent.